# Convert CSV string to list of dicts with memory efficiency

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have CSV data stored entirely in a string `csv_string`. This could reach several gigabytes in size.

I would like to convert it to a list of dicts (not OrderedDicts). Here's the code I currently have for this:

```
csv_string = io.StringIO(csv_string)
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_string)
data = [dict(row) for row in csv_reader]
```

However, as you might imagine this can be quite memory intensive as I end up storing the entire data set in three different objects. Is there a better approach for handling this?

Comment: I don't think you are storing the data in 3 places: The string `csv_string` gets replaced by the `StringIO` of the same name. The csv_reader doesn't store the data, just piping through. And the `StringIO` gets reduced while reading in `for row in csv_reader`. Or have I missed something?

Comment: I might be incorrect in saying that specifically but I have seen from analysing memory usage with pympler that a *lot* of memory is being used while running this block of code. A 1GB string brings memory usage up to several times amount while running this block. The vast majority of that is being used by dict objects.

Comment: Dicts are memory intensive. But as long as you need that structure in `data` in the end, there's no way around it? It depends on what you want to do with `data`. Maybe it's enough to produce the dicts lazily, on demand, instead of ahead, in a list?

Answer (score -1):

I think one of the fastest ways would be to use `pandas`. Using pandas is always nice with big datasets, since it is optimized for these kind of tasks.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.from_csv(csv_string)
data = df.to_dict()
```

or

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.from_csv(csv_string).to_dict()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if pandas takes csv_strings with this funciton and I'm not able to check. You can directly reference the .csv file (if you have access to it) with `pd.from_csv("my_file.csv")`.

Comment: It think you mean [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) instead. And yes, it supports reading a string, but you have to pass it through a buffer with `io.StringIO`. So the correct code would be something like `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_strging))`